# rails render an action with nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested resource as so:

```
resources :contacts do
  resource :leads
end
```

When I render the edit view, the url looks as so:

```
http://localhost:3000/contacts/1/leads/1
```

When I submit the form and it goes to leads controller update action:

```
  def update
    if @lead.update_attributes(lead_params)
      redirect_to contact_lead_path(@lead.contact, @lead)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

When else is triggered, it renders the page as so:

```
http://localhost:3000/leads/1
```

when it should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/contacts/1/leads/1/edit
```

Why doesn't "render :edit" account for the full nested url? How can I resolve this?

Comment: then try to use redirect_to edit_contact_lead_path(@lead.contact, @lead)

Comment: @rjackson yes I already am aware this can be achieved with redirect_to. But I don't want to redirect. I just want to render. Will I be forced to do a redirect here?

Comment: I don't think so. This SHOULD be working as you have it here.
EDIT: Whoops, my mistake. I think I see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the way your form is set up in your view. It should be something like the following. Your `LeadsController#edit` method will need to load both `@contact` and `@lead`.

```
<%= form_for [@contact, @lead] do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

The fact that you're getting the non-nested-resource url from the form suggests that you're not using this pattern, and you should.

Also, I assume this was a typo, but in your question, you're declaring the nested route as

```
resource :leads
```

instead of

```
resources :leads
```

The singular `resource` is valid, but it means something different than what you're intending here, i.e., that each `contact` has one associated `lead`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `render`, the URL seen in the address bar will be the URL that the user was sent to when they submitted the form. In the case of your form, it looks like the URL the edit form submits to is:

`PATCH /leads/1`

When you `render`, it basically sends the content stream as a response to that request. So if you want your `render :edit` call to go to `/contacts/1/leads/1/edit` you need to define a route that responds to 
`PATCH /contacts/1/leads/1/edit` and map that to your `leads#update` action then set the url of your form to that URL. But I'd advise against that since you'd be straying far from Rails conventions.